# Vue3 bind active class to currently clicked button from the list

Tags: pagination, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, conditional-rendering

I want to toggle active class to currently clicked button. There are 5 buttons and I want the active class to only be assigned to the clicked one. I came up with a simple solution but for some reason it doesn't work.

The class is `pagination__control-button--active`.

Javascript:

```js
import { ref } from 'vue';

const activeIndex = ref(0);

const handleActive = (index) => {
    activeIndex.value = index;
};
```

HTML:

```html
<button 
    v-for="(button, index) in buttons"
    @click="goToPage(button);handleActive(index)"
    :class="
        [
            'pagination__control-button pagination__control-button--page-index',
            activeIndex.value == index ? 'pagination__control-button--active' : ''
        ]
    "
    :key="index"
>{{ button }}</button>
```

Im using Vue 3 with Composition API

Answer (score 0):

In Vue class binding works a bit different, check out the documentation:
https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html

For your case, I'd suggest the following:

```
<button 
    v-for="(button, index) in buttons"
    @click="goToPage(button);handleActive(index)"
    class="pagination__control-button pagination__control-button--page-index"
    :class="{'pagination__control-button--active': activeIndex == index}"
    :key="index"
>{{ button }}</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution worked, but there's a catch. I've found out that the conditional statement needs to be: activeIndex == index, for some reason. That's really confusing, considering that accessing refs is done by .value

Comment: @dystrykt9 ah, sorry, I missed that. You don't need `.value` in the template